# How to get Type of arbitrary tree and check its strong/weak conformance?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

For example, one need to check whether an expression is of whole number type: Byte, Short, Int, Long but not Double or Float. The following code doesn't always work:

```
case Apply(Select(q, n), List(rhs)) =>
  if (q.tpe.weak_<:<(typeOf[Long])) true else false
```

For some q their tpe won't be weak conformed even though it has Int type:

```
a.type weak_<:< Long == false
```

`q.symbol.typeSignature` instead of `q.tpe` works correctly, but not all `q` have `symbol != NoSymbol`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `q.tpe` one should use `q.tpe.widen`:

```
case Apply(Select(q, n), List(rhs)) =>
  if (q.tpe.widen.weak_<:<(typeOf[Long])) true else false

Int weak_<:< Long == true
```